# Promise resolver array does not work

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, rxjs

I am using the following code to resolve `promise` outside function scope.

```
private promiseResolver: ()=>void;

getPromise(): Promise<any> {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.promiseResolver = resolve;
        });
}

continueProcessing() {
        this.promiseResolver();
}
```

It works fine however I would like to create an array of `promiseResolver` to resolve multiple promises.

```
private promiseResolvers: [()=>void];

getPromise(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.promiseResolvers.push(resolve);
        });
}

continueProcessing() {
        this.promiseResolvers[0]();
}
```

Somehow caller of the `getPromise()` function does not wait for a promise to resolve when using array.

Is it possible to create such array of `promise` resolvers?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want to achieve here, but have you tried `Promise.all()`?

Comment: Indeed, a use case would be helpful. I'd be very wary of attempting to abstract promise management like this, it sounds a bit like the [deferred . anti pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern).

Comment: As it was said, `promiseResolver` is deferred antipattern. Considering that the question has rxjs tag, you could use observables/subjects instead.

Comment: It was an error with promiseResolvers not initialised but like Nick Tomlin and @estus said, it is an antipattern which was not throwing the error so it was not reporting the root cause. I will change it to observable. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As people said in comments, this is an antipattern, and I shure for 99% that this is not required in your project. But if your project is in that 1%, there is an answer

You may want to do the same but wrapped into "meta"-class like this:

```
class Awaiter{
    constructor(){
        var resolve,
            reject,
            promise = new Promise((_, $) => { resolve = _; reject = $ });
        Object.assign(promise, { resolve, reject })
        return promise
    }
}
```

I see you are using typescript, so there is also typings for this class:

```js
interface Awaiter<T = any> extends Promise<T>{
    resolve: (value?: T) => void
    reject: (reason?: any) => void
}

const Awaiter: {
    new(): Awaiter
    prorotype: Awaiter
}
```

So, as you see, there is no need to use array. Every resolver and rejecter has its own scope.

Example:

```
const myAwaiter = new Awaiter;
(async () => {
    await myAwaiter;
    console.log('awaiter resolved')
})();
setTimeout(() => {
    myAwaiter.resolve()
}, 5000)
```